# Update a select via Chosen Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I have an issue with chosen.jquery.js
when i try to update a list dynamically and write the code below

```
$(selector).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

it works fine, but updating only the select
so the values rendered still as they are with no change

as the rendered values got from a (ul) placed in a div besides the updated select

how can i update the rendered values ?

Comment: Can you show the full code / make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TarekMaksoud/8wykf44s/

here is my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `.trigger('chosen:updated');` after `.append(...)` so that "select changed" now shows up in the selection box.

```
$('#Groups').chosen().change(function (evt, params) {
    $('#Groups').append($("<option/>", {
        value: "test",
        text: "select changed"
    })).trigger('chosen:updated');
});
$('.chosen').empty().trigger('chosen:updated');

$('#Groups').append($("<option/>", {
        value: "1",
        text: ""
    }));
$('#Groups').append($("<option/>", {
        value: "2",
        text: "2"
    }));
$('#Groups').append($("<option/>", {
        value: "3",
        text: "3"
    }));
$('.chosen').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/8wykf44s/2/