# Missing letters after update options tags. JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I'm working with the plugin chosen of jQuery. The problem is when I update the plugin after repopulate my options tags.

.trigger(chose:update).It's a method provided by the plugin that it makes possible update the options in my dropdown. But also it delete what is typed in my input text.

My code is like this:

```
$('#smdlist_chosen input[type="text"]').on('input',  function (){

        var name_1 = $('#smdlist_chosen input[type="text"]').val();

        $('#smdlist option').remove();

            $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "add_guest/search_smd",
            type: 'post',
            data: {name: name_1},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != 'empty') {   
                    $('#smdlist').html(data);


                    $("#smdlist").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $('#smdlist_chosen input[type="text"]').val(name_1);

                }
            }
        });     
    });
```

So if the user type another letter when it's processing my script(type fast), because the way is coded, when  delete and rewrite what is what wrote on the input,  I can miss some letters.

What is a good solution for this?

Comment: so you need to wait for user to finish typing and then call your ajax..correct?

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your code: `$("select").trigger(chose:update)` should be `$("select").trigger("chosen:updated");`

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the problem with the information you provided. Please see [this answer including the JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482499/4571082) and try to create a JSFiddle for your problem and post the link the JSFiddle in your question.

Comment: Well no, for ux I want to update just after the user start to type a new letter. The code was updated @Sameer

Comment: Sorry @gus27 yesterday i was since my phone, the code was updated

Comment: `$('#smdlist_chosen input[type="text"]').val(name);` - you don't appear to have any variable called "name" (other than the one you send to the server in the `data` option, but this cannot be used by the rest of the JS code). So it will replace the text in the textbox with nothing. Should it be `$('#smdlist_chosen input[type="text"]').val(name_1);` perhaps? Although I'm curious why you need to re-populate this anyway, seems like it would get in the way of what the user is typing. Maybe you should just remove this line.

Comment: @ADyson typo mistake. I just want to upload the first 10 results of my database in the dropdown, so if the user type more letters, it will update, and so on... The problem is that when it trigger the .trigger(chose:update),   and after rewrite what is what wrote in the input it can happen that some letters disappear. Because the delete, and rewrite how i explained at the bottom.

Comment: why are you re-writing what was already in the input? What's the reason for that? I think you should just stop doing that, because it will interfere if the user has carried on typing